# Maintain a sorted array that a separate, iterative function can keep accessing

Tags: c, machine-learning

I'm writing code for a decision tree in C.  Right now it gives me the correct result (0% training error, low test error), but it takes a long time to run.

The problem lies in how often I run qsort.  My basic algorithm is this:

```
    for every feature
        sort that feature column using qsort
        remove duplicate feature values in that column
        for every unique feature value
          split
          determine entropy given that split
    save the best feature to split + split value
    for every training_example
      if training_example's value for best feature < best split value, store in Left[]
      else store in Right[]
    recursively call this function, using only the Left[] training examples
    recursively call this function, using only the Right[] training examples
```

Because the last two lines are iterative calls, and because the tree can extend for dozens and dozens of branches, the number of calls to qsort is huge (especially for my dataset that has > 1000 features).

My idea to reduce the runtime is to create a 2d array (in a separate function) where each column is a sorted feature column.  Then, as long as I maintain a vector of row numbers of the training examples in Left[] and Right[] for each recursive call, I can just call this separate function, grab the rows I want in the pre-sorted feature vector, and save the cost of having to qsort each time.

I'm fairly new to C and so I'm not sure how to code this.  In MatLab I can just have a global array that any function can change or access, looking for something like that in C.

Comment: You could use a HashTable to speedup finding unique feature values.

Comment: And your question is? - Antway I'll try to answer: Yes, you can use global variables in C, though it is not good practice. The idea of sorting only once per feature is the way to go. Maybe you could pass to the function the full array of data, a bits (or bools) array indicating which data must be used and which not, and the sorted indexes. Or maybe it's better to create smaller copies of the indexes without the undesired data.

Answer (score 0):

Global arrays in C are totally possible. There are actually two ways of doing that. In the first case the dimensions of the array are fixed for the application:

```
#define NROWS   100
#define NCOLS   100
int array[NROWS][NCOLS];

int main(void)
{
        int     i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < NROWS; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < NCOLS; j++)
        {
                array[i][j] = i+j;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

In the second example the dimensions may depend on values from the input.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int **array;

int main(void)
{
        int     nrows = 100;
        int     ncols = 100;
        int     i, j;

        array = malloc(nrows*sizeof(*array));
        for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        {
                array[i] = malloc(ncols*sizeof(*(array[i])));
                for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
                {
                        array[i][j] = i+j;
                }
        }
}
```

Although the access to the arrays in both examples looks deceivingly similar, the implementation of the arrays is quite different. In the first example the array is located in one piece of memory and the strides to access rows is a whole row. In the second example each row access is a pointer to a row, which is one piece of memory. The various rows can however be located in different areas of the memory. In the second example rows might also have a different length. In that case you would need to store the length of each row somewhere too.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, because I'm not familiar with the terminology of *decision tree*, *feature* and the standard approaches to training sets. But you may also want to have a look at other data structures to maintain sorted data:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red–black_tree maintains a more or less balanced and sorted tree.
2. [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) a bit slower but more balanced and sorted tree.
3. [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) a sorted tree on lists of elements.
4. [Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to easily map a complex element to an integral value that can be used to sort the elements. Good for finding exact elements, but there is no real order in the elements itself.

P.S1: Coming from Matlab you may want to consider a different language from C to move to. C++ has standard libraries to support above data structures. Java, Python come to mind or even Haskell if you are daring. Pointer handling in C can be quite tedious and error prone.

P.S2: I'm unable to include a `-` in a URL on StackOverflow. So the Red-black tree links is a bit off and can't be clicked. If someone can edit my post to fix it, then I would appreciate that.